# Joining a derived table based on specific data from the outside query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to join one record in a table to another using a derived table and am having a bit of trouble figuring out the correct query to do so. What I want to do is have a JOIN of a derived table to a query where the derived table uses where statements depending on data from the outer query that is being joined to. So here is the current code that I am working on:

```
SELECT a.viewerid, a.id, v.id AS entry, a.jobid, v.sourceid, v.cost, a.applicant
FROM a_views a,
JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 1 id, sourceid, cost FROM a_views vt
    WHERE vt.viewerid = a.viewerid
      AND vt.viewed_at <= a.viewed_at
      AND vt.referrer NOT LIKE '%' + vt.hostName + '%'
      ORDER BY viewed_at DESC
) v
```

The derived table is a query of the same table that the outer query uses, and `viewerid` is a FK to itself across the table where `id` is a unique auto-incrementing PK. I need to get the latest record in the a_views table where the viewer id's match, the datestamp (viewed_at) is less than the outer datestamp and the referrer column doesn't contain the hostName column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need [APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT a.viewerid, a.id, v.id AS entry, a.jobid, v.sourceid, v.cost, a.applicant
FROM a_views a
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 id, sourceid, cost FROM a_views vt
        WHERE vt.viewerid = a.viewerid
          AND vt.viewed_at <= a.viewed_at
          AND vt.referrer NOT LIKE '%' + vt.hostName + '%'
          ORDER BY viewed_at DESC
    ) v
```

Since your query has `JOIN` I've gone for `CROSS APPLY`, but you may need `OUTER APPLY` depending on your exact requirements.

Comment: That looks like it worked perfectly. I was just wondering if there is a better way to right the `vt.referrer NOT LIKE '%' + vt.hostName + '%'` I know there is a CONTAINS function in T-SQL, but I can't get the syntax right.

Comment: Using `LIKE` should be fine, `CONTAINS` will be faster (syntax will be `AND NOT CONTAINS(vt.referrer, vt.HostName)`, but this requires the existence of a full text index on vt.Referrer. Another option, although I don't think this will perform any better than like is `CHARINDEX(vt.HostName, vt.HostName) = 0`